# Las imágenes almacenadas en public/storage de mi proyecto con react+inertia+laravel no se muestran al subir el proyecto al hosting

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Hola, el problema consiste en que al subir el proyecto al hosting las imágenes almacenadas en **public/storage** no se cargan devolviendome el error **(404 not found)**, ya he ejecutado el comando **"php artisan storage:link"** y nada aún, la imágenes situadas en **public/img** si se cargan correctamente.

Este es un hosting compartido donde tengo dos dominios y por lo que este segundo proyecto esta fuera de la carpeta public_html.

En un entorno local utilizando laragon para crear host virtuales todo funciona correctamente.

Espero por sus recomendaciones, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

ya he solucionado el problema, todo era problemas de permisos en el hosting, modifique los permisos de la carpeta storage a **2775** y todo funciona, gracias.